# Why is 10 to the power not equal to scientific notation for large numbers in Python?

Tags: python

Why is 10**5 equal to 1e5 but 10**50 is not equal to 1e50 in Python?

```
Python 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 10**5 == 1e5
True
>>> 10**50 == 1e50
False
```

It's true up to 10**22. Then it's false:

```
>>> 10**22 == 1e22
True
>>> 10**23 == 1e23
False
```

Comment: `1e23` is a `float`, so the mathematical inaccuracy is for the same fundamental reason as every other mathematical inaccuracy with floating-point.

Comment: I agree -- OP probably didn't think to check the type (if they did, the significance of it being float may be lost on them; that's all the canonical addresses), and the behavior about when the cutoff occurs is Python-specific.

Comment: Maybe I'm too tired, but if there is a difference due to limited precision of floating point numbers, why this difference cannot be displayed as a floating point number? `(10**50 - 1e50) == 0.0` is True

Comment: If you are doing computations with high numbers like this I strongly recommand to use `numpy.isclose()` or `numpy.allclose()` for arrays to check if 2 numbers are equals within a tolerance.

Comment: @VPfB because the comparison coerces both sides to a float first. Explicitly converting to `decimal.Decimal` helps.

Comment: @o11c Sir could you elaborate your comment a bit (how does "comparison coerces both sides to a float first" cause `(10**50 - 1e50) == 0.0)` to be True)? or provide a reference link if it is possible.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I'm not sure it's documented anymore; it used to be documented using the out-of-line `coerce` function.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Could be this the reference you are lookig for? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#arithmetic-conversions

Comment: @VPfB Exactly ! thank you.

Comment: @o11c So in fact **arithmetic operator** causes this conversion not the **comparison operator**, that's the reason why `(10**50 - 1e50) == 0.0` is True, They both become float first, then the result of subtraction is `0.0`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary Er, right. My bad.

Comment: @o11c If you force the coercion the other way: `10**50 - int(1e50)` the result is `-7629769841091887003294964970946560`.

Answer (score 13):

Python 3 supports big integers and uses them whenever it can. `10**50` is a calculation on integers and produces the *exact* number ten to the fiftieth power. On the other hand, scientific notation *always* uses floating point, so `1e50` is a [floating-point value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) that's *approximately equal to* ten to the fiftieth power.

```
>>> type(10 ** 50)
<class 'int'>
>>> type(1e50)
<class 'float'>
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! I wanted to delete this question as I just checked print(int(1e78)) which was not actually a number with 1 and 78 zeroes because of float precision.

Comment: I strongly recommend against deleting the question. It's a fair question that could easily help someone else. If you think you have more insight into the answer, then by all means post a second answer with your findings. The more, the merrier!

Comment: For reference, on my machine: `1e23 == 10**23 - 8388608`

Comment: Another note: `10.0**50` equals `1e50` (because both floats)

Comment: *"Python 3 supports big integers"* - As does Python 2.